# Angular routes setup when app is deployed in subdirectory

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app that I'm deploying in foobar.com/myapp directory on my webserver.

The build command I use is `ng build -bh /myapp` to make sure that my index.html contains the

```
<base href="myapp">
```

line. All the assets and required files load up fine. On the main page I have a router outlet and my routing setup is as follows:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'configure', component: ConfigureComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'myapp',
    redirectTo: '/configure',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/configure',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

The problem I am facing is that if I open up the url `http://foobar.com/myapp` directly, I am landing on the `ConfigureComponent` as expected, but the URL gets rewritten to `http://foobar.com/myapp/myapp/configure`. On the `ConfigureComponent`, I have a link:

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard" class="btn btn-primary">Save and go to Dashboard</a>
```

When I click on it, it takes me to the `DashboardComponent` fine, but the URL is again `http://foobar.com/myapp/myapp/dashboard`.

I tried to play around with different route configs, but did not manage to set it up the way that eliminates this duplication in the URL. What I don't quite like here is that the app has to have the `myapp` subdirectory name hardcoded in it, although I would like to make it completely agnostic of the subfolder where I deploy it. (apart from that I have to specify it in the `ng build -bh ...`.

What am I doing wrong here..?

Comment: when you deleting duplicate in your URL field it sends you to a right route?

Comment: No, it does not. If I manually switch to foobar.com/myapp/configure, it's 404

Comment: What the route comes when you not specifying base href?

Comment: Actually this is not route config problem, because routing withing angular app have no influence on your base route. You need to look at directories path, and play with base href, because depending on server preferences app may be deployed with some baseUrl by its own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base should have a traling slash. Try `ng build -bh /myapp/`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would have been kind from `ng build` if there was a warning, or if it added that automatically :-)

Comment: Yeah :D It's totally valid without, but can't see why anyone would need one without.